# How to mock functionality of boto3 module using pytest

Tags: python, unit-testing, pytest

I have a custom module written called sqs.py. The script will do the following:

1. Get a message from AWS SQS
2. Get the AWS S3 path to delete
3. Delete the path
4. Send a confirmation email to the user

I'm trying to write unit tests for this module that will verify the code will execute as expected and that it will raise exceptions when they do occur.

This means I will need to mock the response from Boto3 calls that I make. My problem is that the code will first establish the SQS client to obtain the message and then a second call to establish the S3 client. I'm not sure how to mock these 2 independent calls and be able to fake a response so I can test my script's functionality. Perhaps my approach is incorrect. At any case, any advice on how to do this properly is appreciated.

Here's how the code looks like:

```
import boto3
import json
import os
import pprint
import time
import asyncio
import logging
from send_email import send_email

queue_url = 'https://xxxx.queue.amazonaws.com/1234567890/queue'

def shutdown(message):
    """ Sends shutdown command to OS """
    os.system(f'shutdown +5 "{message}"')

def send_failure_email(email_config: dict, error_message: str):
    """ Sends email notification to user with error message attached. """
    recipient_name = email_config['recipient_name']
    email_config['subject'] = 'Subject: Restore Failed'
    email_config['message'] = f'Hello {recipient_name},\n\n' \
                           + 'We regret that an error has occurred during the restore process. ' \
                           + 'Please try again in a few minutes.\n\n' \
                           + f'Error: {error_message}.\n\n' \
    try:
        send_email(email_config)
    except RuntimeError as error_message:
        logging.error(f'ERROR: cannot send email to user. {error_message}')

async def restore_s3_objects(s3_client: object, p_bucket_name: str, p_prefix: str):
    """Attempts to restore objects specified by p_bucket_name and p_prefix.

    Returns True if restore took place, false otherwise.
    """

    is_truncated = True
    key_marker = None
    key = ''
    number_of_items_restored = 0
    has_restore_occured = False
    logging.info(f'performing restore for {p_bucket_name}/{p_prefix}')
    try:
        while is_truncated == True:
            if not key_marker:
                version_list = s3_client.list_object_versions(
                    Bucket = p_bucket_name,
                    Prefix = p_prefix)
            else:
                version_list = s3_client.list_object_versions(
                    Bucket = p_bucket_name,
                    Prefix = p_prefix,
                    KeyMarker = key_marker)

            if 'DeleteMarkers' in version_list:
                logging.info('found delete markers')
                delete_markers = version_list['DeleteMarkers']
                for d in delete_markers:
                    if d['IsLatest'] == True:
                        key = d['Key']
                        version_id = d['VersionId']

                        s3_client.delete_object(
                            Bucket = p_bucket_name,
                            Key = key,
                            VersionId = version_id
                        )
                        number_of_items_restored = number_of_items_restored + 1

            is_truncated = version_list['IsTruncated']
            logging.info(f'is_truncated: {is_truncated}')

            if 'NextKeyMarker' in version_list:
                key_marker = version_list['NextKeyMarker']

        if number_of_items_restored > 0:
            has_restore_occured = True

        return has_restore_occured

    except Exception as error_message:
        raise RuntimeError(error_message)

async def main():
    if 'AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID' in os.environ \
            and 'AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY' in os.environ \
            and os.environ['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'] != '' \
            and os.environ['AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'] != '':
                sqs_client = boto3.client(
                    'sqs',
                    aws_access_key_id=os.environ['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'],
                    aws_secret_access_key=os.environ['AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'],
                    verify=False
                )
                s3_client = boto3.client(
                    's3',
                    aws_access_key_id=os.environ['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'],
                    aws_secret_access_key=os.environ['AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'],
                    verify=False
                )
    else:
        sqs_client = boto3.client(
            'sqs',
            verify=False,
        )
        s3_client = boto3.client(
            's3',
            verify=False,
        )

    received_message = sqs_client.receive_message(
        QueueUrl=queue_url,
        AttributeNames=['All'],
        VisibilityTimeout=10,
        WaitTimeSeconds=20,    # Wait up to 20 seconds for a message to arrive
    )

    if 'Messages' in received_message \
        and len(received_message['Messages']) > 0:
        # NOTE: Initialize email configuration
        receipient_email = 'support@example.com'
        username = receipient_email.split('@')[0]
        fullname_length = len(username.split('.'))
        fullname = f"{username.split('.')[0]}" # Group name / First name only

        if (fullname_length == 2): # First name and last name available
            fullname = f"{username.split('.')[0]} {username.split('.')[1]}"

        fullname = fullname.title()

        email_config = {
            'destination': receipient_email,
            'recipient_name': fullname,
            'subject': 'Subject: Restore Complete',
            'message': ''
        }

        try:
            receipt_handle = received_message['Messages'][0]['ReceiptHandle']
        except Exception as error_message:
            logging.error(error_message)
            send_failure_email(email_config, error_message)
            shutdown(f'{error_message}')

        try:
            data = received_message['Messages'][0]['Body']
            data = json.loads(data)
            logging.info('A SQS message for a restore has been received.')
        except Exception as error_message:
            message = f'Unable to obtain and parse message body. {error_message}'
            logging.error(message)
            send_failure_email(email_config, message)
            shutdown(f'{error_message}')

        try:
            bucket = data['bucket']
            prefix = data['prefix']
        except Exception as error_message:
            message = f'Retrieving bucket name and prefix failed. {error_message}'
            logging.error(message)
            send_failure_email(email_config, message)
            shutdown(f'{error_message}')

        try:
            logging.info(f'Initiating restore for path: {bucket}/{prefix}')
            restore_was_performed = await asyncio.create_task(restore_s3_objects(s3_client, bucket, prefix))

            if restore_was_performed is True:
                email_config['message'] = f'Hello {fullname},\n\n' \
                                    + f'The files in the path \'{bucket}/{prefix}\' have been restored. ' \

                send_email(email_config)
                logging.info('Restore complete. Shutting down.')
            else:
                logging.info('Path does not require restore. Shutting down.')
            shutdown(f'shutdown +5 "Restore successful! System will shutdown in 5 mins"')

        except Exception as error_message:
            message = f'File restoration failed. {error_message}'
            logging.error(message)
            send_failure_email(email_config, message)
            shutdown(f'{error_message}')

        try:
            sqs_client.delete_message(
                QueueUrl=queue_url,
                ReceiptHandle=receipt_handle,
            )
        except Exception as error_message:
            message = f'Deleting restore session from SQS failed. {error_message}'
            logging.error(message)
            send_failure_email(email_config, message)
            shutdown(f'{error_message}')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    logging.basicConfig(filename='restore.log',level=logging.INFO)
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.run_until_complete(main())
    loop.close()
```

Comment: You should use [`moto`](https://github.com/spulec/moto)

Comment: alternatively to moto, you could be looking into unittest mock or stubber from botocore.stub

Answer (score 0):

The only way I was able to mock Boto3 is rebuilding a small class that represents the actual method structure. This is because Boto3 uses dynamic methods and all the resource level methods are created at runtime.

This might not be industry standard but I wasn't able to get any of the methods I found on the internet to work most of the time and this worked pretty well for me and requires minimal effort (comparing to some of the solutions I found).

```py
class MockClient:
    def __init__(self, region_name, aws_access_key_id, aws_secret_access_key):
        self.region_name = region_name
        self.aws_access_key_id = aws_access_key_id
        self.aws_secret_access_key = aws_secret_access_key
        self.MockS3 = MockS3()

    def client(self, service_name, **kwargs):
        return self.MockS3


class MockS3:
    def __init__(self):
        self.response = None # Test your mock data from S3 here

    def list_object_versions(self, **kwargs):
        return self.response


class S3TestCase(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_restore_s3_objects(self):

        # Given
        bucket = "testBucket" # Test this to something that somewahat realistic
        prefix = "some/prefix" # Test this to something that somewahat realistic
        env_vars = mock.patch.dict(os.environ, {"AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID": "abc",
                                                "AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY": "def"})
        env_vars.start()

        # initialising the Session can be tricy since it has to be imported from 
        # the module/file that creates the session on actual code rather than 
        # where's a Session code is. In this case you might have to import from
        # main rather than boto3.
        boto3.session.Session = mock.Mock(side_effect=[
            MockClient(region_name='eu-west-1',
                       aws_access_key_id=os.environ['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'],
                       aws_secret_access_key=os.environ['AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'])])
        s3_client = boto3.client('s3', verify=False)

        # When
        has_restore_occured  = restore_s3_objects(s3_client, bucket, prefix)

        # Then
        self.assertEqual(has_restore_occured, False) # your expected result set
        env_vars.stop()
```